# How to use an array as $haystack and $array[$i] (string) as needle in php?

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

The code is:

```
<?php
$notes = array("Main/folder/02/12.jpg = twelve",
               "Main/folder/02/16.jpg = sixteen"
               );
$imglist = array( "12.jpg",
                  "13.jpg",
                  "14.jpg",
                  "15.jpg",
                  "16.jpg"
                  );
for ($i=0;$i<(count($imglist));$i++){
    if(in_array($imglist[$i], $notes)){
        echo $imglist[$i];
        //Get key($notes) and //Cant figure out how to implement this key();
        echo $notes[$key];
    } //if ENDS
} //for ENDS
?>
```

What I need is that for $i=0 and $i=4, if() should return TRUE & do the echoes.

The pseudo-code/logic is:

- Iterate through all the $imglist array one by one.
- if the complete $imglist[$i] string is found anywhere in $notes array, get the key/index of that value in $notes, and echo $notes[$key] and $imglist[$i]. OR Echo $notes[$key].

For example the desired output of this for loop should be:

```
12.jpg Main/folder/02/12.jpg = twelve
16.jpg Main/folder/02/16.jpg = sixteen
```

The problem is that now this all code is just outputting none. Means that if condition is not returning TRUE ever. Whereas in theory it should return TRUE when $i is 0 & 4. Is my if() condition wrong? Is php not taking $imglist[$i] as a string? Should I use strpos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) uses a loose comparison to search for elements and will not yield the results you're looking for.

Instead, you need to use your own logic (using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) as you guessed) to implement the functionality you desire, like so:

```
foreach( $imglist as $image_key => $image)
    foreach( $notes as $notes_key => $note)
        if( !(strpos( $note, $image) === false))
            echo "$image $note\n";
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/SpiJTA):

```
12.jpg Main/folder/02/12.jpg = twelve
16.jpg Main/folder/02/16.jpg = sixteen
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, same like @Pox However, I have modified it to use for loops instead of foreach, because I have always problems wrapping my head around foreach statements. The code is here http://codepad.org/l4V7zkgQ It now also echoes the iteration(Although I have not asked it in question). Have a look and Thanks again.

Comment: One thing, does it make any difference by checking that if IF condition returns TRUE (as in my code linked in upper comment) as compared to yours one, where you are saying IF NOT FALSE. I am using IF TRUE.

Comment: Yes, because `strpos()` could return 0, which will be wrongly interpreted by your version. [Here is an example](http://codepad.org/WSSPiJbw) of when it will fail. To fix your version, you need to compare the return of `strpos()` with `!== false`

Comment: got it :) it will return int(0), which is not TRUE, so gotta use !== false

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using strpos()

```
$notes = array("Main/folder/02/12.jpg = twelve",
           "Main/folder/02/16.jpg = sixteen"
           );
$imglist = array( "12.jpg",
              "13.jpg",
              "14.jpg",
              "15.jpg",
              "16.jpg"
              );


foreach($imglist as $image){
 foreach($notes as $key => $note){
$position = strpos($note,$image);
if ($position !== false){
 echo "$image $note <br>";  
}
}
}
```